# Tkinter filedialog.asksaveasfilename() not saving files

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a text editor, but the <kbd>Save As</kbd> function is not working.
I've been making the program with `tkinter` in pycharm and the <kbd>Open</kbd> function is working fine.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title('TextPad')
root.geometry('1200x600')

# Create new file function
def new_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)
    root.title('New - TextPad')
    status_bar.config(text="New File      ")

# Open Files
def open_file():
    my_text.delete("1.0", END)

    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=("Desktop"), title="Open File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")) )

    name = text_file
    status_bar.config(text=f'{name}         ')
    name = name.replace("C:/Documents", "")
    root.title(f'{name} - TextPad')

    text_file = open(text_file)
    stuff = text_file.read()

    my_text.insert(END, stuff)

    text_file.close()

def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", initialdir="C:/savefiles/", title="Save File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if text_file:
        # Update Status Bars
        name = text_file
        status_bar.config(text=f'{name}         ')
        name = name.replace("C:/savefiles", "")
        root.title(f'{name} - TextPad')


my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(pady=5)

text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fil=Y)

my_text = Text(my_frame, width=97, height=25, font=('Helvetica', 16), selectbackground="yellow", selectforeground="black", undo=True, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
my_text.pack()

text_scroll.config(command=my_text.yview)

my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="New", command=new_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As", command=save_as_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

edit_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
edit_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Paste")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Undo")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Redo")

status_bar = Label(root, text='Ready       ', anchor=E)
status_bar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, ipady=5)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As the function's name implies (and the documentation states), [`asksaveasfilename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) only returns the name of a file, it doesn't actually save anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @martineau mentioned, the `save_as_file` function does not actually save to a file. You just need to add a couple lines to the end of the function.

```
def save_as_file():
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".*", initialdir="C:/savefiles/", title="Save File", filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("Python Files", "*.py"), ("All Files", "*.*")))
    if text_file:
        # Update Status Bars
        name = text_file
        status_bar.config(text=f'{name}         ')
        name = name.replace("C:/savefiles", "")
        root.title(f'{name} - TextPad')
        with open(text_file,'w') as f:   # add these lines
            f.write(my_text.get("1.0", "end-1c"))  # remove newline
```

Comment: That should be `my_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")` otherwise you'll get an extra newline added by tkinter.